# is it possible to run multiple apps on android at the same time?

Tags: android

I want to run many apps on the same emulator at the same time. Then get the i/o streams of these apps, and allow them to be controlled to through web browsers, or an applet.
Is it possible?

Basically, I want to build a similar service like Amazon that allows user to see apps running on emulator through browser. Now, if only one activity is shown on the screen at a time, I would need to create a emulator for every user. That wouldn't be feasible. So I need a workaround. And if multiple apps could be run on emulator and their I/O could be programaticaly handled, it would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean many different apps at the same time, or the same app many times on the same device?

Comment: different apps at the same time, on the same device. So that I would be able to catch the output (i.e display) of each app and stream it to a user. And collect input from user, and stream to the app on emulator.

Comment: To do that you would have to get the needed app to the foreground (only 1 can be on the foreground at a time) and do the actions.. I think its a lot of work but should not be impossible. You will only know for sure if you try or find someone who has tried this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do. In Android, you can run several applications at the same time, but only one at a time will be on the foreground (visible to the user). But yes, you can have several applications running in the background syncing, downloading data, logging stuff, etc.

For what you want, you might consider using [live android project](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) as it is a *much* lighter solution to run.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the one Pedro Loureiro posted is about to (or is already) stopped production. Right now the best program for this job would be this: [link](http://www.android-x86.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's why you also have task killers.